# quality standards

Tags: support

I have a question which I cannot submit because of "quality standards". I could add more text to try to get round this but that would be filler text.

What is the accepted way to handle this situation?

Comment: could you add the body of that question here? Maybe we can suggest additional information to add to it. There's *always* more useful information to add!

Answer (score 3):

Add filler text and then edit it back down after it's posted.

I'm slightly concerned that you can't flesh out the body a little to get past this filter. It's there to make sure people give a good context to their questions.

Comment: Maybe but sometimes there is simply not very much context to provide. If I ask "How can I get Thunderbird to do X?", then there may be little more to say. It would be better to have form following function than having to warp questions to fit a specific form

Comment: So if users take the time to ask, an exception can be made?